# chgrp : Operation not permitted?

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have this simple line of code:

```
      mkdir($path_to_rpi, 0755);
      chgrp($path_to_rpi, 'sambashare');
```

Directory is created as **www-data** and group is the same. **www-data** owns the directory and yet the chgrp fails?!?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps www-data does not have permission to add a directory to that group.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...www-data creates the directory fine and the owner and group by default are www-data...I should be able to chgrp no???

Comment: I am not 100% sure, look this up, but I imagine that if the user is not a member of the group the directory is being given to, this it can't give it.

Comment: I am not sure I explained myself clearly...The user 'www-data' is a default user account for apache, the group as well. When the folder is created it's under www-data as owner and group. There is no other group, AFAIK.

Comment: But is the user `www-data` a member of the group `sambashare`? If not, then the operation is not permitted.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493582/need-to-reboot-xubuntu-to-make-chgrp-work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Confirming my comment:

> You must be a member of the group to which you are changing ownership to.

<s>http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/tasks/change_own.html</s>

(dead link; use this one: https://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/UNIXhelp/tasks/change_own.html)

Comment: I'm still missing something :) www-data is the user and the group...www-data is already a member of group www-data (I used groups www-data to confirm this).

Comment: Lets try something.  You be `www-data` and i'll be `sambashare`.  You try to give me your directory, and I say, "you don't have permission to give me that", you ask, "why not?", and I reply, "because you are not a member of MY group".

Comment: OK I added www-data to sambashare group and that still didn't allow the PHP code to chgrp :(

Comment: www-data may need to log back in.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after doing that? Group membership changes don't affect running processes.

Comment: OK I shall restart apache

Comment: Thanks guys much appreciated...I just learned something new about file permissions and linux and it fixed my problem so it seems :)

Comment: @Alex.Barylski Assuming that this transaction of permissions is one of only a few cases between apache and samba, it may be better for you to create a separate group and add each of them to it.  That way you dont give them unnecessary access to other files they own with group-writable permissions.

Comment: Any idea as to why permission bits now aren't changing? I set 'uploads' to 0775 on one sub-directory inside the directory previously created...but doesn't have any affect.

Comment: I'm seeing this while doing sudo rsync dafuuuq

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this myself today.  This was the best post on the subject that I found but there is no clear answer, just a few comments of various merit.  So here's a concise summary.

```
--Setup--
User  : apache
Group : web
Goal  : make a new directory 'newone' owned by apache and group of web
Verify: >ls -l shows: drwxr-xr-x 2 apache web  4096  ...   newone

step 1:  apache must be a member of group web (@Flosculus answer)
check : > grep ^web /etc/group
to add: > usermod -a -G web apache

step 2: restart apache (@Andrew Mecidoo comment)
restart: > service httpd restart

step 3: make the directory
PHP: mkdir('newone', 0755);
PHP: chgrp('newone', 'web');

step 4: verify permissions
verify : > ls -l
```

worked for me.  hope it helps you out.